# Drupal6: how to deny to see other user's nodes?

Tags: drupal-6, cck

I have the following problem in Drupal 6 with CCK:

user1 creates node 1 in a custom CCK type

user2 creates node 2 in a custom CCK type

If user1 puts in address bar http://website_address?q=node/2   he can see the content of the node, even if I've given permissions only for own created content.

What can I do to give "permission denied" when trying to see nodes that are not created from the owner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,
i've found private module http://drupal.org/project/private that makes exactly what i need.